# Rename of Team Project

Tags: tfs

I have several TFS projects that need to be renamed or copied and deleted. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no (easy) way to rename a TFS project - read the [Renaming Team Project in VS2008](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/08/renaming-team-project-in-vs2008-nothing.html) article.

So far the only way to do it is to create a new project and move relevant elements (source code, work items, etc.) over.

Answer (score 0):

You can now rename team projects in Visual Studio Online and in the upcoming Team Foundation Server 2015 release: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-apr-24-vso